# Spark Regex regexp_extract error with backslash: Error in SQL statement: NullPointerException

Tags: regex, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset where I need to extract the alias in a domain style format: domain\alias where the alias is after the backslash.  The backslash seems to be treated as an escape character despite a few attempts at getting it to be treated as a character.  I first tested my regex pattern using a known non-escape character, the forward slash with success. I then tried the same pattern with the backslash and then several permutations with methods familiar to me to get regex to treat the backslash as a character and not as an escape character without success.  What do you do to get this regex pattern to work with a backslash in spark?

Regex Pattern Verification

```
select regexp_extract('domain/alias', '/(.*)') as test --Results: alias Works with forward slash.
```

Permutations and Results

```
select regexp_extract('domain\alias', '\(.*)') as test --Results: domainalias Removes the backslash for some reason

select regexp_extract('domain\alias', '"""\"""(.*)') as test --Results: empty string

select regexp_extract('domain\alias', '"""\\"""(.*)') as test --Results: empty string

select regexp_extract('domain\alias', '\\(.*)') as test --Results: Error in SQL statement: NullPointerException: 

select regexp_extract('domain\alias', '\\\(.*)') as test --Results: Error in SQL statement: NullPointerException:
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by adjusting a spark setting. In the Databricks cluster I was using I ran this:

```
set spark.sql.parser.escapedStringLiterals=true;
```

My regex pattern now worked as intended:

```
select regexp_extract('domain\alias', '\\(.*)') as test --Results: alias
```